# SQL Server : trigger not working, Syntax Error near From

Tags: sql-server, triggers, case, inner-join

I try to create a trigger which checks after insert if a `TO_DELETE = 1` got inserted. If yes, the trigger shall also check if in another table (test2) the `USERGROUP_ID` is identical to the `I.USERGROUP_ID` and the `TO_DELETE` flag in this table is 0. If that's the case, the trigger shall raise an error and rollback the transaction.

I tried for hours now, but i can't find my mistake. The error message is "error near FROM")

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Test_Trigger
ON  dbo.Test1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @delete_count numeric(1,0),
            @usergroup_count numeric(1,0),
            @email_count numeric(1,0)

    UPDATE T
    SET @delete_count = CASE I.TO_DELETE WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    SET @usergroup_count = CASE dbo.Test2.USERGROUP_ID WHEN I.USERGROUP_ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    SET @email_count = CASE dbo.Test2.TO_DELETE WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

    IF (@delete_count != 0 AND @usergroup_count != 0 AND @email_count != 0)
    BEGIN   
       RAISERROR (50001,11,1) WITH NOWAIT
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END

    FROM dbo.Test1 AS T
    INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I ON dbo.Test1.USERGROUP_ID = I.USERGROUP_ID
END
```

Comment: You can't use if -statement in the middle of the update statement.

Comment: And if you're not actually updating anything, I would suggest using select to get the values to the variables, but remember that there can be more than one row in inserted.

Comment: Yes, that it is the next problem. I don't know yet how to handle it.

Comment: If you're just checking for error situations, most likely you'll need to create something like "if (exists (select 1 from inserted i where exists (select 1 from Test1 ...))) begin rollback ... "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty tough to figure out what you are really trying to do here but it seems like using EXISTS would be a good approach. Not really sure what you are trying to do with all those variable in the code you posted but that could be other functionality you didn't post. I would think something like this should be pretty close.

```
if exists
(
    select *
    from inserted i
    join test2 t on t.PK = i.PK and t.USERGROUP_ID = i.USERGROUP_ID
    where t.TO_DELETE = 0
)
    RAISERROR (50001,11,1) WITH NOWAIT
    --ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    --I would recommend not putting the rollback in your trigger. If you have some other code
    --that expects this transaction it will throw an exception. Let the exception
    --bubble back up to the application
```

Comment: yes, i think EXISTS is what i searched for. I got the other solution running in the meanwhile, but i'll try if your code does also fix the problem. thank you (and the others) very much!

Comment: Keep in mind that the other solution is using scalar values in your trigger. That is a clear sign there is an issue because it can't handle multiple row operations. I know of at least one business that went under because all of their tables had triggers like that.

Comment: yes, the original code is in oracle and i'm translating it. my colleagues said that there comes one row only. but is your code able to deal with multiple rows?

Comment: Oracle triggers are different than sql server. In sql server they fire once per operation. That means if you insert, update or delete multiple rows the trigger fires only 1 time. The way I coded this checks for the existence of ANY rows that violate the condition you want to prevent from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Too many things wrong in your `sql` like unwanted `set` statement, `If` condition inside a `update`. Try this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Test_Trigger
ON dbo.Test1
AFTER INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @delete_count    NUMERIC(1, 0),
              @usergroup_count NUMERIC(1, 0),
              @email_count     NUMERIC(1, 0)

      UPDATE T
      SET    @delete_count = CASE I.TO_DELETE
                               WHEN 1 THEN 1
                               ELSE 0
                             END,
             @usergroup_count = CASE T.USERGROUP_ID
                                  WHEN I.USERGROUP_ID THEN 1
                                  ELSE 0
                                END,
             @email_count = CASE T.TO_DELETE
                              WHEN 0 THEN 1
                              ELSE 0
                            END
      FROM   dbo.Test1 T
             INNER JOIN INSERTED AS I
                     ON T.USERGROUP_ID = I.USERGROUP_ID

      IF ( @delete_count != 0
           AND @usergroup_count != 0
           AND @email_count != 0 )
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (50001,11,1) WITH NOWAIT

            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
  END
```

Comment: Thanks so far, but it still doesn't work. I get the error "Msg 4104 - The multi-part identifier could not be bound." concerning "dbo.Test2.USERGROUP_ID and "dbo.Test2.TO_DELETE"

Comment: @Tom - yeah there was a mistake i missed it now updated check

Comment: This still has a major problem. It won't work for multiple rows operations. If two rows are inserted you have no way of knowing which row is which.

Comment: @SeanLange yes i know. i found several approaches i'll try later, but first i need to fix this problems. but if you have an idea how to do it, it would be great to hear.

Comment: i added a second inner join to query the test2 table also.